# Magento can't save new products anymore

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Everything was fine 'til this morning. I've tried clearing cache, re indexing, all tips I could find on the internet.
Here is the message I'm getting
Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /home5/rockbott/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php on line 578

here is line 577 and 578:

```
   if (Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
        $product->setWebsiteIds(array(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsite()->getId()));
```

A newly created product gives me Fatal Error message. Duplicated product gives me the same, but when I go to manage products it appears, but without SKU# and 0 stock count. When I try to edit that product again - I get Fatal Error.
Please help me with my problem.

Thanks in advance.

---

Thanks for your response.
Someone suggested that I clear log file and I did. I'm sorry I don't have the log file. Compiler is disabled as well. Would you be kind enough to take a look here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/347764/ I've posted more information there including reports.
Thank you
Anna

Comment: Are you perhaps loading new products using an import module?

Comment: have you tried to update your store?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is old, but on a Magento 1.9.0.1 install i was having the same problem. I'm not sure what is happening but enabling the cache allowed it to work for me. Weird.

Comment: Running into this same issue and I can't be sure when it showed up. Enabling cache does allow products to save, but going back and disabling cache causes it to return.

Answer (score 1):

What appears to be causing it in my case is a remnant logging line in `Mage.php` that I was using to track events.

On line 447 I had:

```
Mage::log($name, null, 'events.log');
```

Removing this logging line resolved the issue.

Comment: this one fixed my issue. not sure why though.

Answer (score 0):

With your informations is difficult to find the problem.
Can you paste your system.log file?

One question: Do you have the compiler enabled? Try to disable it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Someone suggested that I clear log file and I did. I'm sorry I don't have the log file. Compiler is disabled as well. Would you be kind enough to take a look here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/347764/ I've posted more information there including reports. Thank you Anna

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error. Solution turned out to be very simple: you need to replace **getStore(true)** to **getStore(1)**. 
Its very strange because in PHP **true** same as **1** ... but in this it was a mistake. If you make a "more correct" and write:

```
$product->setWebsiteIds(array(Mage::app()->getStore(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->getWebsite()->getId()));
```

Magento give you not true website. Was too lazy to look for, as well as programmers Magento (getStore (true)) :)) so I decided to leave it

Comment: This might provide relief, but it offers no reason why this happens. I have a local install of a store where this issue started showing up, but the staging site that is running the same code base does not have the same symptoms.